# Hiding .Rproj.user when building packages developed in RStudio

Tags: r, package

A package's `.Rbuildignore` looks like this:

```
^.*[.]Rproj.*$
^\.Rproj\.user$
^.Rhistory$
[~]
```

Yet `R CMD check mypackage --as-cran` returns:

```
* checking for hidden files and directories ... NOTE
Found the following hidden files and directories:
  .Rproj.user
```

From reading around, it looks like this is a "feature not a bug".  But how do I just prevent `.Rproj.user` from appearing in the package file in the first place?  Or do I have a problem with my regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.Rbuildignore is used to ignore files when building the package.  If you build the package, the files that were ignored will not be in it.  I think you are probably trying to check the source instead of checking the build.  Try this

```
R CMD build mypackage
R CMD check mypackage_1.0.tar.gz --as-cran
```

[Writing R Extensions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-exts.html#Checking-packages) says:

> It is strongly recommended that the final checks are run on a tar archive prepared by R CMD build.

Comment: That was it.  I foolishly assumed that since I didn't have to specify a filename when building I didn't have to when checking.  Thanks!